# Looking for software so I can spin up a quick test site with temp URL based on GIT feature branch

Tags: wordpress, magento, testing, automation

I'm looking for some software (web based ideally) that will allow me to spin up quick clones of my live website(s) for client approval/testing purposes on to a temporary URL.
Ideally I'd be able to specify a GIT feature branch to deploy to it so my client only sees the exact features they are approving (as there could be lots of work in progress on the current test site).

As an example:
My client wants to see what a new module looks like on mysite.com.
Currently I would add the module to my local project and test (wamp), commit to GIT feature branch, push, then create a new staging/test server by dumping/tarring, uploading, creating hosting space, etc etc etc.
This is really time consuming and expensive.

I don't even know if anything like this even exists but if it does I'd love to hear about it! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

3 options, fastest/easier > longest

Create a skeleton of the website, only the basics.

1a. Use Node.JS to deploy a temp webserver on localhost.
(Exemple, you can deploy a linux machine where you host (with IP, no domain name) where you can display you PoCs

1b. Display PoC for your modules.

2. If that's not good enough, create a separate folder, on target(client) server where you can upload the "testing website" you'll use and password lock it (mydomain.com/testsite/).
3. Use Snapshot to make a snap of client server (if you want to display the PoC on his server/website)